# Regex: find all sentence with a citation

Tags: python, regex

I've found this code to detect all citation in a text:

```
author = r"(?:[A-Z][A-Za-z'`-]+)"
etal = r"(?:et al\.?)"
additional = f"(?:,? (?:(?:and |& )?{author}|{etal}))"
year_num = "(?:19|20)[0-9][0-9]"
page_num = "(?:, p\.? [0-9]+)?"  
year = fr"(?:, *{year_num}{page_num}| *\({year_num}{page_num}\))"
regex = fr'\b(?!(?:Although|Also)\b){author}{additional}*{year}'
```

It's actually working great, but I need to find all the sentence (from where it start after a dot untile the end, another dot) where the citation is. So in this example:

```
"Nothing is here. In this line, actually, there is a ciation (Author et al., 2022). Once again, In this line there is nothing."
```

I'd like to get this  `"In this line, actually, there is a ciation (Author et al., 2022)."`

How should I edit the above code to achieve this?

Comment: Describe in plain English how you imagine to differentiate between a dot after an abbreviation and a dot at the end of the sentence.

Comment: If you are not going to handle abbreviations, `regex = fr'[^.?!]*\b(?!(?:Although|Also)\b){author}{additional}*{year}[^.?!]*[?!.]?'` will help. See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/AwjB33).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regular expression:

```py
r"\s*([^.]+(?=\([\w ,.]+(, *\?)?(\d{4}|\d{2})\)\.?))(\([\w ,.]+(, *\?)?(\d{4}|\d{2})\)\.?)"
```

Proof [here](https://regex101.com/r/YErcYC/1).

Comment: Thank you! That works! The only problem is that when there are two citation with "et al.," next to each other the sentence is also cut (For example if I have "`some word (Author1 et al., 2021) something (Author2 et al., 2022`)" I only get "`some word (Author1 et al.,`") and not the whole sentence. The same problem if there is a number like `"2.45"` or other word like `"e.g"` Is there a way to exclude this from the code above? Thanks again

Comment: Can you edit your question with an updated exampled?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one:

```
(?<=\. )[^(]+\(([^)]+)\).*?\.
```

Explanation:

- `(?<=\. )`: lookbehind that checks for previous sequence of dot and space
- `[^(\.]+` : any combination of characters other than open parentheses and dots
- `\(`      : open parenthesis
- `([^)]+)` : any combination of characters other than closed parenthesis
- `\)`      : closed parenthesis
- `.*?`     : optional lazy combination of characters
- `\.`      : sequence of dot and space

Corner cases that this solution is not able to address:

- `<space><dot><word>` (like  `.dotnet`) is an inner word before parenthesis: it will always treat `<space><dot>` as begin of sentence.
- `<word><dot><space>` (like `e.g.`) is an inner word after parenthesis: it will always treat `<dot><space>` as end of sentence.

One possibility of addressing these corner cases is to do some preprocessing first and transforming/removing any abbreviation present in the raw text.

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/2SvMVL/3).

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve the problem in two steps: a) break the text into sentences, b) detect sentences with a citation. Sentence tokenization is non-trivial to do right, so use a library to do it. For example:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> text = "Nothing is here. In this line, actually, there is a citation (Author et al., 2022). Once again, In this line there is nothing."
>>> sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
>>> print(sentences)
['Nothing is here.', 'In this line, actually, there is a citation (Author et al., 2022).', 'Once again, In this line there is nothing.']
```

Then, using your definitions:

```
>>> citation = fr"{author}{additional}*{year}" 
>>> for s in sentences:
>>> ...     if re.search(citation, s):
>>> ...             print(s)
>>> ... 
In this line, actually, there is a citation (Author et al., 2022).
```

PS. If you've never used the nltk before, you'll need to do a one-time download for the sentence tokenizer. You'll see an error message telling you to run this, just do it once and you're done forever.

```
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Comment: The problem is that if he has a text like `In this line there is some citation e.g. (Author et al., 2022). In this line there is nothing.`, there's no reasonable way of correct sentence splitting, because it can happen right after the closed parenthesis, but also right after `e.g. `.

Comment: @lemon, properly punctuated this would be `"... some citation, e.g., ..."`, which the nltk's segmenter handles correctly. Anyway, you are right that statistical methods are not 100% accurate but that's no reason to reject them when there is no better alternative.